# Images are not showing in recycler view

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I'm facing this issue with my Recyclerview. I'm trying to display images from another firebase database that I have. It was working fine before and now I get two blank card view and no image when I run my app. I am not sure what is going on because it worked fine before. Can someone please help me with this issue. Thanks in advance.
My code below

```
//Code

 recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1);

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        myUploads = new ArrayList<Model>();
        aAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity2.this, myUploads);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
        aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        progressBar=findViewById(R.id.progressBar);



        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance("https://puttt0-4331.firebaseio.com").getReference("Images");


        databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                if(snapshot.exists()){

                    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Model upload=postsnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
                        //myUploads.clear();

                        myUploads.add(upload);
                        aAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity2.this, myUploads);
                        recyclerView.setAdapter(aAdapter);
                        //aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        recyclerView.invalidate();


                    }







                    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: Can you tell us what all changed between the " working fine before" and now?

Comment: @ShubhamRohila I think I am now seeing the problem. I will have to ask another question. I'm getting that glide is not showing the image for some reason I get this message saying Glide: Load failed for null with size [0x0]

Answer (score 1):

You should not

```
setAdapter(newAdapter)
```

each time you get new data from the OnDataChange() method

here is what you should do:

```
if(snapshot.exists()){
    myUploads.clear();
    for (DataSnapshot postsnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {
        Model upload=postsnapshot.getValue(Model.class);
        myUploads.add(upload);
    }
    aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Try this and tell me what happens. And always remember you have to have ONLY ONE initialization for the adapter, i.e.

```
aAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity2.this, myUploads);//this should only be done only once for the adapter
```

Comment: Thanks for responding. Quick question where am I supposed to put aAdapter = new Adapter(MainActivity2.this, myUploads); if not inside onDataCange?

Comment: In the place where you instantiate all new things like if you are in an Activity onCreate() would be a good place, and if you are inside a fragment you can do that inside  onViewCreated(), other verrry important thing to put in mind is the data list (myUploads in ur case) make sure neverrrrrrr  ever create a new instance of it, just clear the old one and refill it, then call aAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

Comment: I tested everything and I just get a blank white page

Comment: maybe I don't see the whole picture, if you want me to get into screensharing call with to help I am ok, communicate with me on this mail: m.elsayed.hamouda@gmail.com

Comment: Ok,Now I i am still getting the two blank card view again